# Origin of the abbreviation St. for Street

Tags: etymology, american-english, abbreviations

What is the origin of the abbreviation St. for Street?

Why did an address such as

> 123 Fake **Street**

Become

> 123 Fake **St.**

?

---

This question  is related to a [history stackexchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/60045/was-street-more-common-than-the-abbreviated-st-in-pre-1910-american-newspap) question about the observed historical trend in US print newspaper to use St. instead of Street when printing addresses.

It appears, according to one answer on the history question that the following curious facts arise

1. There does appear to be some historical trend from one form to another in american newspaper print (Street to St)
2. The shortening from Street to St. only saves 2 symbols in print, rising to the theory that it is related to when listing of people and their addresses became common ( e.g. first phonebooks)
3. The US Postal Service apparently officially requires/prefers the abbreviation (Section 211 of [USPS Publication 28](https://pe.usps.com/cpim/ftp/pubs/Pub28/pub28.pdf))

Comment: This seems like a very intuitive abbreviation.  What is there not to get?

Comment: Are you more interested in "when" (possibly answerable) or "why" (probably not definitively answerable) the abbreviation gained popularity?

Comment: FWIW, the postal service preference has to do with the use of optical character recognition (OCR) for mail routing, which began only in the 1980's or so. So it's probably not related to the earliest uses of "St." as an abbreviation for "street".

Comment: " only saves 2 symbols in print". It's early here, but the symbols r, e, e and t seem to be replaced by a full stop. That seems to save 3 symbols, plus a replacement of a standard-width e with a very narrow period, so space-wise it saves almost 4 symbols width?

Comment: @oerkelens A more interesting question is why "road" is shortened to "rd." since that only saves one character, This is even odder when you think that "ave." is as long and "road" and "cresc." is as long as "street" when the dots are counted and both of them are used rather than "av." and "cr." in many cases.